# How to use regex correctly with this REGEXEXTRACT function?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm dealing with a large spreadsheet of order data which uses a unique, sort of hashed string of syntax to represent order items and attributes.

I currently have this data in Google Sheets and I'm hoping to be able to make use of the REGEXEXTRACT function (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) to retrieve the pieces of information I need from each row.

Example of function: REGEXEXTRACT("Needle in a haystack", ".e{2}dle")

Order data is huge and I believe I can use this regex function to isolate the piece of information I want.

Examples of the portion of string snippets I need to work with. Keeping in mind the actual order string is much longer than this:

- "Location\";s:5:\"value\";s:7:\"Atlanta\"
- "Location\";s:2:\"value\";s:8:\"New York\"
- "Location\";s:5:\"value\";s:15:\"barrio de boedo\"

So the common string in each row is Location, as value is used multiple times throughout each order.

Let me see if I can articulate this correctly: **How would I use regex to specify the value between the 4th and 5th double quotes occurring immediately after the string 'Location' so that in my examples above, the results would be Atlanta, New York, barrio de boedo?**

For reference, the barrio de boedo example in its entirety:
*\";s:7:\"product\";s:2:\"31\";s:8:\"form_key\";s:16:\"aasdf\";s:7:\"options\";a:2:{i:1;s:1:\"2\";i:2;s:15:\"barrio de boedo\";}s:15:\"super_attribute\";a:2:{i:92;s:1:\"4\";i:132;s:1:\"9\";}s:3:\"qty\";s:1:\"1\";}s:7:\"options\";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:5:\"label\";s:15:\"Language-Gender\";s:5:\"value\";s:8:\"spa-male\";s:11:\"print_value\";s:8:\"spa-male\";s:9:\"option_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:11:\"option_type\";s:9:\"drop_down\";s:12:\"option_value\";s:1:\"2\";s:11:\"custom_view\";b:0;}i:1;a:7:{s:5:\"label\";s:8:\"Location\";s:5:\"value\";s:15:\"barrio de boedo\";s:11:\"print_value\";s:15:\"barrio de boedo\";s:9:\"option_id\";s:1:\"2\";s:11:\"option_type\";s:5:\"field\";s:12:\"option_value\";s:15:\"barrio de boedo\";s:11:\"custom_view\";b:0;}}s:15:\"attributes_info\";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:\"label\";s:5:\"Color\";s:5:\"value\";s:4:\"Grey\";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:\"label\";s:4:\"Size\";s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"L\";}}s:11:\"simple_name\";s:14:\"T-Shirt-Grey-L\";s:10:\"simple_sku\";s:14:\"t-shirt-Grey-L\";s:20:\"product_calculations\";i:1;s:13:\"shipment_type\";i:0;}"*

Comment: So, have you tried any pattern yet? Where are you stuck? Do you really have escaped double quotes, or is it a copy/paste issue? A small screenshot with your real data might help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've provided an example of order syntax in its entirety without modification. I can find the word "Location" but I'm not sure how to specify that I want to retrieve the value between the 4th and 5th double-quotes occurring after that.

Comment: Ok, but I am still not sure if you have ``\`` there or not. Try `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "Location(?:""[^""]*){3}""([^""]+)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the escapes \ do exist in the data I'm having to work with. I tried what you provided but no luck. I guess I'm just trying to figure out how to specify a range after a string occurrence. The formula returned an error in the spreadsheet but I really just need to know the regex matching pattern.

Comment: Ok, try `"Location\\?(?:""[^""]*){3}""([^""]+)\\"""`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Whoa! It worked! That's incredible! Thank you so much. If you post as answer, I will readily accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following pattern in `REGEXEXTRACT`:

```
"Location\\?(?:""[^""]*){3}""([^""]+)\\"""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvvhH5/1).

The pattern is `Location\\?(?:"[^"]*){3}"([^"]+)\\"` and it matches:

- `Location` - a substring `Location`
- `\\?` - 1 or 0 `\` symbols (the `?` makes a pattern optional)
- `(?:"[^"]*){3}` - exactly 3 occurrences (due to the limiting quantifier `{3}`) of a `"` followed with zero or more (due to the `*` quantifier) chars other than `"`  (the `[^...]` is a negated character class that matches any chars but those defined in the class)
- `"` - a single double quote
- `([^"]+)` - *capturing group #1* (whose contents will be returned with `REGEXEXTRACT`): 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier) chars other than `"`
- `\\"` - a `\"` substring.

[image]